Ubuntu has been stuck on "Starting System halt..." when halt it
When I run sudo halt on my Ubuntu virtual machine (in Windows 11), the screen has been stuck on "Starting System halt..." for over 15 minutes. I'm not sure if it has successfully halted or if it's still processing. Is it safe to power off this VM at this point?


Yup, your system has halted. If that's what you want, go ahead and power it down.

If you want it to power down, sudo poweroff might be what you want.
